# CSS only: how to make a div the width of its biggest row, with children as inline-blocks?

Tags: html, css

Problem:

I want to center the containing div, but I want to also left-align the blocks.
I think flex boxes might be the solution, but I'm not sure what to do with them.
I want to do this:

- without Javascript
- without tables
- without setting a row width (the row width must be dynamic.. that's the intent of this exercise)
- without setting a width to the container. (same as setting a row width)
- without adding invisible divs. (same as setting a row width)

Example, with current CSS (attempt failed):

```
.block {
 border  : 5px solid DarkRed;
 width   : 150px;
 height  : 150px;
 display : inline-block;
}
.container {
 display    : inline-block;
 text-align : center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SKRjG/

Edit: here is a Javascript version to show how it *should* look like:
http://jsfiddle.net/SKRjG/8/

Comment: Flexbox cannot do this (see:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18218668/even-flexbox-product-grid-with-left-alignment)

Comment: @cimmanon: that's a bit different!

Comment: No it isn't.  The desired visual appearance might differ slightly, but the same limitations apply.  Flexbox is just as effective as text-align in this instance.

Comment: Which limitations?... "Flexbox is just as effective as text-align in this instance." : ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your divs within another container so that it looks like

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="subcontainer">
    <div class="Block"></div>ETC
  </div>
</div>
```

Then have @media queries to change the width of .subcontainer to fit your blocks into perfect grids. Then center your .subcontainer div with margin: 0 auto;

Css might look like:

```
.block {
 border  : 5px solid DarkRed;
 width   : 150px;
 height  : 150px;
 display : inline-block;
}
.subcontainer {
    text-align:left;
    margin:0 auto;
}
/*Three columns*/
 @media (min-width: 495px){
.subcontainer{width:495px;}
 }
/*Four columns*/
 @media (min-width: 660px){
.subcontainer{width:660px;}
 }
/*Five*/
@media (min-width: 825px){
.subcontainer{width:825px;}
 }
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TM2wB/26/

Comment: I suppose that is *technically* correct, but would prefer not having to specify media queries for each column size.

Answer (score 0):

Use this *CSS*

```
.block {
 border  : 5px solid DarkRed;
 width   : 150px;
 height  : 150px;
 display : inline-block;
 float:left;
 clear:both;
}
.container {
 display    : inline-block;
 text-align :center;
 margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work too well. It works less when the implied space nodes are removed: http://jsfiddle.net/SKRjG/7/

Comment: Don't you want to use fix width of container?

Comment: Huh? Check the fiddle. Also, look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/SKRjG/8/ This is a Javascript solution.