# Flexbox : grow all items but last line

Tags: css, flexbox

I currently have this simple Flexbox layout:

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>lorem</li>
    <li>ipsum</li>
    <li>dolor</li>
    <li>sit</li>
    <li>amet</li>
    <li>consectetur</li>
    <li>adipisicing</li>
    <li>elit</li>
    <li>sed</li>
    <li>do</li>
    <li>eiusmod</li>
    <li>tempor</li>
    <li>incididunt</li>
    <li>ut</li>
    <li>labore</li>
    <li>et</li>
    <li>dolore</li>
    <li>magna</li>
    <li>aliqua</li>
</ul>
```

I would like my elements to fill the container width (as now), but leave the last line left aligned. As you can see, the last line attempts to fill the space, and this sometimes makes the last elements to get an ugly width.

Does Flexbox allows us to do that ? I can't find a way to do it.

Comment: See answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16377972/how-to-align-left-last-row-line-in-multiple-line-flexbox?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: It was the first solution that came to my mind, but I'm not a big fan of adding extra markup. Plus, this only works for fixed-width elements, so this won't work here.

Comment: If your items have the same width, it is better to use [CSS grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/). For 3 columns: `display:grid;grid-template-columns:33.3% 33.3% 33.3%`.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You can add an `::after` pseudo-element with a huge `flex-grow`, so that the `flex-grow: 1` of the `li` elements will be negligible:

```css
ul::after {
  content: '';
  flex-grow: 1000000000;
}
```

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: #ddd;
}
ul::after {
  content: '';
  flex-grow: 1000000000;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>lorem</li>
  <li>ipsum</li>
  <li>dolor</li>
  <li>sit</li>
  <li>amet</li>
  <li>consectetur</li>
  <li>adipisicing</li>
  <li>elit</li>
  <li>sed</li>
  <li>do</li>
  <li>eiusmod</li>
  <li>tempor</li>
  <li>incididunt</li>
  <li>ut</li>
  <li>labore</li>
  <li>et</li>
  <li>dolore</li>
  <li>magna</li>
  <li>dolore</li>
  <li>magna</li>
  <li>aliqua</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Small remark to others: this only works for a left-aligned flexbox.

Answer (score 9):

You can also append empty items with `height: 0` to the container and make them take up for the extra space: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OyOqrG

(Source copied from my codepen:

```
<div class="container">
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  ...
  <p class="empty"></p>
  <p class="empty"></p>
</div>



.container {
  max-width: 490px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  background-color: #00f;
}

.container p {
  min-width: 90px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: #f00;
  height: 90px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.container p.empty {
  height: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: That's genius, it fits more responsive situations than the `flex-grow: 1000000000;` solution. Append n-1 `<span class="empty"></span>` as the number of max col in your grid, IE : I have 4 columns max on bigger screens, 3 `.empty` will fit every responsive situation

Answer (score 6):

Faced the same problem and solved it with css grid. Last rule of the grid is aligned left and all the elements have the same width.

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
```

```css
ul {
  display: grid;
  gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>lorem</li>
    <li>ipsum</li>
    <li>dolor</li>
    <li>sit</li>
    <li>amet</li>
    <li>consectetur</li>
    <li>adipisicing</li>
    <li>elit</li>
    <li>sed</li>
    <li>do</li>
    <li>eiusmod</li>
    <li>tempor</li>
    <li>incididunt</li>
    <li>ut</li>
    <li>labore</li>
    <li>et</li>
    <li>dolore</li>
    <li>magna</li>
    <li>aliqua</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That is the way to go, nowadays. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Completely fixed my problem and made me learn more about grid in the process, upvoted

Comment: Use `auto-fill` instead of `auto-fit` to ensure that if you only have one element, it doesn't stretch the whole row. [here](https://css-tricks.com/auto-sizing-columns-css-grid-auto-fill-vs-auto-fit/) is an article with the difference between the two

Answer (score 1):

You can set the pseudo `::last-child`. All `<li>` grow except last one

**CSS**

```
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: #ddd;
}

li:last-child {
  flex-grow: 0;
 }
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/xabbwrct/8/)**

Comment: Pretty close, but we still have the problem with items on the last line, which are **not** the last child. We would need a `::last-line` pseudo-element.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove `flex-grow: 1` on li and add `justify-content: space-between` on ul

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>lorem</li>
    <li>ipsum</li>
    <li>dolor</li>
    <li>sit</li>
    <li>amet</li>
    <li>consectetur</li>
    <li>adipisicing</li>
    <li>elit</li>
    <li>sed</li>
    <li>do</li>
    <li>eiusmod</li>
    <li>tempor</li>
    <li>incididunt</li>
    <li>ut</li>
    <li>labore</li>
    <li>et</li>
    <li>dolore</li>
    <li>magna</li>
    <li>aliqua</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ow... the last line is unfortunately not left-aligned (if we've got more than one element)

Comment: The `li` elements won't grow in this case, so there will be gaps between their backgrounds. Still, that might be fine for some situations.

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATE:** Turns out I didn't understand correctly, I misread the question as looking to target only the last *item* in the list, rather than the last *line*. Will leave the below here, though, for the benefit of anyone who trips over this question in the future and may find it helpful.

If I'm understanding you correctly then, to achieve what you want, you'll need to set the `flex-grow` property on all *but* the last item which you can do by combining the [negation pseudo class `:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) with the [`:last-child` pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child), like so:

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
li:not(:last-child) {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
li {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>lorem</li>
    <li>ipsum</li>
    <li>dolor</li>
    <li>sit</li>
    <li>amet</li>
    <li>consectetur</li>
    <li>adipisicing</li>
    <li>elit</li>
    <li>sed</li>
    <li>do</li>
    <li>eiusmod</li>
    <li>tempor</li>
    <li>incididunt</li>
    <li>ut</li>
    <li>labore</li>
    <li>et</li>
    <li>dolore</li>
    <li>magna</li>
    <li>aliqua</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This makes it not grow the same size as other children